# Text Underline output table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, underline

Im trying to get user input and select the style of the text that he wants and output the selected select style into a table

but the underline is not showing along with the test that the user wrote
Im trying to get user input and select the style of the text that he wants and output the selected select style into a table

```js
var row = 1;

function show()
{
    var style = document.getElementById("textstyle").value;
    var table = document.getElementById("tablee");
    var input = document.getElementById("textt").value;
    var output = input;
    
    
    

    var add = table.insertRow(row);
    var add1 = add.insertCell(0);
    var add2 = add.insertCell(1);
    var add3 = add.insertCell(2);
    
    
    
    if(style=="Bold")
    {
        
        output=output.bold();
    }
    if(style=="Italic")
    {
        
        output=output.italics();
        
    }
    if(style=="Underline")
    {
        var t=createTextNode(input)
        var x=document.createElement("U");
        x.appendChild(t);
        
        document.table.appendChild(x);
        
        add1.innerHTML = style;
        add2.innerHTML = input;
        
        
    }
    else{
    
        add1.innerHTML = style;
        add2.innerHTML = input;
        add3.innerHTML = output;
    }
    
    row++;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Question4(Pair)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="PairQ4.css">
    <script src = "PairQ4.js"></script>
    
    
</head>

<body>
    <label>Please Enter a sentence</label></br></br>
    <input type="text" id="textt" name="textt"></br></br>
    
    
    <label>Select a style :</label>
    
    <select class="txtstyle" id="textstyle">
        <option  value="Bold"> Bold </option>
        <option  value="Italic"> Italic </option>
        <option  value="Underline"> Underline </option>
        <option  value="Strikethrough"> Strikethrough </option>
        <option  value="Highlight"> Highlight </option>
    </select></br></br>

    
    
    <table id = "tablee"> 
     <tr> 
     <th>Format</th> 
     <th>Description</th>
     <th>output</th> 
     </tr>
     
     </table>
     </br></br>
     <input type= "button" value="Submit" onclick="show()">
     
     
    

</body>
```

but the underline is not showing along with the test that the user wrote
i would like the users input to display in the table when he selects underline

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your underline condition to this, and now it's working:

```
if(style=="Underline"){
  var x=document.createElement("U");
  x.textContent = input;
  
  add1.innerHTML = style;
  add2.innerHTML = input;
  add3.appendChild(x);
}
```

```js
var row = 1;

function show()
{
    var style = document.getElementById("textstyle").value;
    var table = document.getElementById("tablee");
    var input = document.getElementById("textt").value;
    var output = input;
    
    
    

    var add = table.insertRow(row);
    var add1 = add.insertCell(0);
    var add2 = add.insertCell(1);
    var add3 = add.insertCell(2);
    
    
    
    if(style=="Bold")
    {
        
        output=output.bold();
    }
    if(style=="Italic")
    {
        
        output=output.italics();
        
    }
    if(style=="Underline")
    {
        var x=document.createElement("U");
        x.textContent = input;
        
        add3.appendChild(x);
        
        add1.innerHTML = style;
        add2.innerHTML = input;
        
        
    }
    else{
    
        add1.innerHTML = style;
        add2.innerHTML = input;
        add3.innerHTML = output;
    }
    
    row++;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Question4(Pair)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="PairQ4.css">
    <script src = "PairQ4.js"></script>
    
    
</head>

<body>
    <label>Please Enter a sentence</label></br></br>
    <input type="text" id="textt" name="textt"></br></br>
    
    
    <label>Select a style :</label>
    
    <select class="txtstyle" id="textstyle">
        <option  value="Bold"> Bold </option>
        <option  value="Italic"> Italic </option>
        <option  value="Underline"> Underline </option>
        <option  value="Strikethrough"> Strikethrough </option>
        <option  value="Highlight"> Highlight </option>
    </select></br></br>

    
    
    <table id = "tablee"> 
     <tr> 
     <th>Format</th> 
     <th>Description</th>
     <th>output</th> 
     </tr>
     
     </table>
     </br></br>
     <input type= "button" value="Submit" onclick="show()">
     
     
    

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

by adding below line your problem solved:

```
add3.innerHTML = "<span style='text-decoration: underline;'>"+output+"</span>";
```

```js
var row = 1;

function show()
{
    var style = document.getElementById("textstyle").value;
    var table = document.getElementById("tablee");
    var input = document.getElementById("textt").value;
    var output = input;
    
    
    

    var add = table.insertRow(row);
    var add1 = add.insertCell(0);
    var add2 = add.insertCell(1);
    var add3 = add.insertCell(2);
    
    
    
    if(style=="Bold")
    {
        
        output=output.bold();
    }
    if(style=="Italic")
    {
        
        output=output.italics();
        
    }
    if(style=="Underline")
    {
        
        add1.innerHTML = style;
        add2.innerHTML = input;
        add3.innerHTML = "<span style='text-decoration: underline;'>"+output+"</span>";
        
    }
    else{
    
        add1.innerHTML = style;
        add2.innerHTML = input;
        add3.innerHTML = output;
    }
    
    row++;
}
```